# Execute File.Fis in Matlab From C# using Interop.MLApp.dll

Tags: c#, matlab

I have tried call function `file.m` using `MLApp`. Now I want to call `file.fis` using command in Matlab `Evalfis`. How can I invoke `file.fis` using `MLapp`?
here is the code I've tried before:

```
            MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();

            // Change to the directory where the function is located 
            matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\MATLAB");

            // Define the output 
            object result = null;

            // Call the MATLAB function myfunc
            matlab.Feval("multiplication", 1, out result, 3, 5);

            // Display result 
            object[] res = result as object[];

            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(res[0]));
```